# Flex Mobile: Add an event to Calendar

Tags: android, ios, air, flex-mobile

Is it possible to programatically add an event to a Calendar on iOS and Android? I guess there has to be an Adobe Native Extension for this, right? Or is there any other way.

Comment: You'll have to write a native extension to do so; assuming the underlying OS exposes APIs to do that.

Comment: The underlying OSs do expose the necessary APIs, but I don't know about Flex extensions for them...

Answer (score 1):

check this extension, it look like it does what u need

http://code.google.com/p/flashbuilder-ane-save-date-as-calendar-events/